# Heroku verification

Tags: payment, verification, dyno, eco, usd

Why do I keep getting the error message "Could not complete the action. Please try again later." While trying to verify my account using USD debit card in Nigeria for Eco Dyno payment?

I was trying to add my USD debit card for Dyno payment.